# How to open terminal and run script and then close it by discord bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot to start my minecraft sever via discord. That what I have at the moment.

```
import os
import discord
import subprocess

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content == 'server!start':
        await message.channel.send('Loading ngrok...')
        #run terminal with ngrok
        await message.channel.send('Loading minecraft server...')
        #run terminal with minecraft server
    if message.content == 'server!stop':
        await message.channel.send('Stopping server...')
        #stop minecraft and ngrok by killing terminal
```

As in code, I want to open terminal and execute bash script to run server and then, when it's time to turn it off, I want to kill terminal or send "stop" into console.

EDIT: I tried to use subprocess.Popen, but I can't close it from another if statment than i execute that first time

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content == 'server!start':
        await message.channel.send('Loading ngrok...')
        ngrok = subprocess.Popen("/home/administrator/minecraft/server/startngrok.sh", shell=True)
        #run terminal with ngrok
        await message.channel.send('Loading minecraft server...')
        minecraft = subprocess.Popen("/home/administrator/minecraft/server/startserver.sh", shell=True)
        #run terminal with minecraft server
    if message.content == 'server!stop':
        await message.channel.send('Stopping server...')
        ngrok.terminate()
        server.terminate()
        #stop minecraft and ngrok by killing terminal
enter code here
```

That's the output:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/administrator/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/administrator/minecraft/bot/bot.py", line 25, in on_message
    ngrok.terminate()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ngrok' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? what are the options you think that are gonna work?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to use subprocess.Popen. It's allows me to open the terminal and runs servers, but i can't terminate it in another statment than i run them.

Comment: It seems like you are on the right track. Have you looked into how to terminate subprocesses? here's a good start [How to terminate a subprocess in Python](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-terminate-a-subprocess-in-python#:~:text=terminate()%20to%20terminate%20a,terminate%20the%20subprocess%2C%20call%20subprocess.)

Please do your research and try to implement it

Comment: I think I've done everything like on this site, but I can't terminate it. I'm still getting an error. Look at the EDIT.

Comment: The error is very self-explanatory. It basically means at that scope level, it doesn't know what `ngrok` is. You should fix your scope so the subprocess object can be accessible for both if statements

Answer (score 0):

The current error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ngrok' referenced before assignment`
This means that 'ngrok' wasn't initialized (defined) before the `ngrok.terminate()` was called. It happened because you initialize your ngrok in the `if` conditional above, but say, what if you never run through that conditional? Then `ngrok` will never be defined as anything. What you want to do is initialize it first.

```py
import os
import discord
import subprocess

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # define 'ngrok' variable
    ngrok = null
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content == 'server!start':
        await message.channel.send('Loading ngrok...')
        ngrok = subprocess.Popen("/home/administrator/minecraft/server/startngrok.sh", shell=True)
        #run terminal with ngrok
        await message.channel.send('Loading minecraft server...')
        minecraft = subprocess.Popen("/home/administrator/minecraft/server/startserver.sh", shell=True)
        #run terminal with minecraft server
    if message.content == 'server!stop':
        await message.channel.send('Stopping server...')
        # If 'ngrok' is a NoneType, catch it
        try:
            ngrok.terminate()
        except AttributeError:
            # exception message or desired except code
        server.terminate()
        #stop minecraft and ngrok by killing terminal
```

However, I don't see server defined anywhere as well. More errors may arise. If you would like more assistance, please provide [sample reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Nope, it's doesn't work. It's just giving me this exception message all the time. I tried to define `ngrok` and `server` local and global but both options don't works (I used `None` to define null)

Comment: It’s hard to determine what exactly is going on. Please provide steps to reproduce your code.